# py -3 --version and python3 --version gives two different versions. Is this intended? Should they be the same?

Tags: python, windows, path, environment-variables

```
$ py -3 --version
Python 3.7.1

$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.3
```

Is it supposed to be this way? I vaguely remember reading that `py -3 --version` should point to the most recent version.

I only have one system variable that I have set **my self**. And that is:

`C:\Users\A331144\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts`

In this folder, though, none of `python.exe` nor `py.exe` exists.

If I search for ´python.exe´ and if I chooses open in location I get to:

`C:\Python27`

Which ofc is wrong version. But `python3.exe` is not found.

and for `py.exe` I get path:

`C:\Windows`

I guess these two paths are already on my path since my commands work.

Why cant I find `python3.exe`? Why does `python3` and `py -3` versions differ? Is it possible to make them the same (should they be made the same)?

Comment: _Why cant I find `python3.exe`?_ Did you try `where python3` (without `.exe` extension)? Try `where python*` as well.

Comment: @JosefZ `$ where python3` gives `C:\Devtools\Install\Cygwin\3.0.7\bin\python3`. And `where python*` gives that all python binaries are in the same path as previous.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add output from both  **1.** `set py` **2.** `where /R C:\ python.exe` (be patient, could take a significant time amount). If the latter output contains something like `C:\Python\Python37\python.exe` then `py.exe` launcher takes it?